# openvpn3 not working after upgrading to ubuntu 23.04

Tags: server, ssh, openvpn

here is the output of session-start command.

```
  openvpn3 session-start --config config.ovpn
    Using configuration profile from file: config.ovpn
    Session path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/1a5cd198s7d95s4d6bs8299s8b5c3522d413
    Auth User name: <username>
    Auth Password: <password>
    ** Aborted **
    ** ERROR ** Failed to disconnect tunnel (object does not exist)
```

I have tried uninstall and install of openvpn3.

Comment: The same situation after building and installing OpenVPN from GitHub. (after upgrading to 23.04) No logs: $ openvpn3 log --log-level 6 --config /home/user/vpn/config.ovpn Waiting for session to start ... Done Attaching to session /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/8f9736a6s464cs4aads9de9s539dbef03190 Session closed EDIT:
fixing is in progress
https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/issues/171#issuecomment-1516303214

Answer (score 1):

openvpn3 has not released apt repository for ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar) distribution Need to wait for release for OpenVPN community
for details [Go here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux?_ga=2.260486670.2052257428.1682310303-232748535.1681796541&_gl=1*hax0tj*_ga*MjMyNzQ4NTM1LjE2ODE3OTY1NDE.*_ga_SPGM8Y8Y79*MTY4MjQwNjg0Ni44LjEuMTY4MjQwNjk1NS4xOC4wLjA.)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had the same issue after upgrade to ubuntu 23 it worked after adding data-ciphers AES-128-CBC in the config file

Comment: I have tried updaing the data ciphers to 128, but still not working. as per the open issue https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/issues/171#issuecomment-1516303214
the issue seems related to glib2 version and it will be fixed in the openvpn3 version 21 release cycle.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** - I was facing same issue with openvpn client on ubuntu 22.10 and 23.04, i have tested this on both **Ubuntu 22.10 and 23.04**

1. **Download the "libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb"** file and install it. from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/libssl1.1/1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12

Direct download link: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/23231923/+files/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/23231923/+files/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb)

go to download folder and run:

`sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb`

2. **Download the "openvpn_2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.4_amd64.deb"** file from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/openvpn/2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.4

Direct download link: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/23493657/+files/openvpn_2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.4_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/23493657/+files/openvpn_2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.4_amd64.deb)

run:

`sudo dpkg -i openvpn_2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.4_amd64.deb`

now try to connect you vpn

if still failling then Reinstall NetworkManager OpenVPN GUI
run

`sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`

Comment: I haven't tried this and it might work for OpenVPN 2.4.7 but I need to install openvpn3 which is essential for our organization which is failing because of known issue with glib in latest ubuntu 23.04 (https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/issues/171#issuecomment-1516303214)